# No USB bus file even after enabling usbmon in Android kernel?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, usb, tcpdump

I have enabled usbmon in the linux kernel for Android on a device that has USB host already (Rooted Nexus 7, 2012, WiFi, Android version 5.0.2). After booting from the new kernel, tcpdump -D shows:

```
1.any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces) [Up, Running]
2.lo [Up, Running, Loopback]
3.p2p0 [Up]
4.wlan0 [Up] 
5.nflog (Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface)
6.nfqueue (Linux netfilter queue (NFQUEUE) interface)
7.usbmon1 (USB bus number 1)
```

but running tcpdump -i usbmon1  results in

```
tcpdump: Can't open USB bus file /sys/kernel/debug/usbmon/1t: No such file or directory
```

and in fact there is no usbmon folder in that location. Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you have a  /sys/kernel/debug/-folder ?

Comment: Yes, which contains usb/devices but not usbmon.

Comment: How did you "activate" usbmon? With [M] module or [Y] built in?

Comment: It's built-in, (not through module).

Comment: On my system, usbmon in  debugfs is in fact located in /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/ and not /sys/kernel/debug/usbmon/ where you tcpdump seems to look for it. Maybe you tcpdump-version is too old or too new.

Comment: libpcap, not tcpdump, looks for it (tcpdump uses libpcap), and libpcap has looked in /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon (as well as /sys/kernel/debug/usbmon/) since at least libpcap 1.2.0, possibly back to 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

To access debugfs-components it needs to be mounted. Which might not be done automatically on you system. If so try:

```
mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
```

If you compiled usbmon as a module it has to be loaded manually.

```
modprobe usbmon
```

Answer (score 0):

I had not flashed the device with the newly compiled kernel, but I was only booting it with fastboot, so in case there's anything wrong, I can turn it off and reboot with the original boot image. 
Even though the new kernel was loaded, as verified in the "kernel version" section, the system folders for usbmon were not created, **until** I flashed the device with the new kernel.